# Router setting to access computer via its external IP

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I use DD-WRT on my router. A few years ago I happened across a setting that allowed me to access my own computer (e.g. using the browser while a web server was running) using the computer's external IP or hostname. Previous to that, I could access any other computer; and I could access my computer using its external IP or hostname, but only from *another* computer.

Now, I again can't seem to access my computer via its external IP *on* my computer. I don't remember the terminology for the setting I changed. **My question is**: what setting is it that enables this functionality?

Comment: Just a quick guess : `DMZ`.